# How to merge an array of objects into a single string?

Tags: javascript

I try to merge an array of objects into a single string, but got a bit lost. The input looks like that:

```
  const array = [
    {
      key: "title",
      text: " Example Text title",
    },
    {
      key: "description",
      text: "Example Text description",
    },
    {
      key: "video",
      text: "Example Text video",
    },
  ];
```

Expected Output:

```
"title: Example Text title, description: Example Text description, video: Example Text video"
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: `array.map(({key, text}) => `${key}: ${text}` ).join(',')`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ``myArray.map(({key, text}) => `${key}: ${text}` ).join(', ');`` --> Prefer to not have a variable named `array`. So, used `myArray`.

Comment: What will you do if there are already colons  and commas in your strings?

Comment: Thanks, the "join" approach works for my case. This might be worth a answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a single string out of this, and not an array, you will want to use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to concatenate onto an existing string object, like so:

```js
let outStr = '';

array.forEach((ele, idx) => 
    outStr += `${ele.key}: ${ele.text}${idx < array.length ? '' : ', '}`
);
```

You could also use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like the folks in the comments above suggested, but you will need to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the result to produce a single string at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = [
    {
      key: "title",
      text: " Example Text title",
    },
    {
      key: "description",
      text: "Example Text description",
    },
    {
      key: "video",
      text: "Example Text video",
    },
];

let result = "";

array.forEach((object, index) => {
    result += `${object.key}: ${object.text}`
    if(index < array.length - 1) {
        result += ', ';
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope the following is useful for you.

```
const array = [
    {
      key: "title",
      text: " Example Text title",
    },
    {
      key: "description",
      text: "Example Text description",
    },
    {
      key: "video",
      text: "Example Text video",
    },
  ];

array.map(item => `title: ${item.text}, description: ${item.text}, video: ${item.text}`).toString()

//'title:  Example Text title, description:  Example Text title, video:  Example Text title,title: Example Text description, description: Example Text description, video: Example Text description,title: Example Text video, description: Example Text video, video: Example Text video'
```